# How to separate time from datetimepicker vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetimepicker

I have one datetimepicker which custom format **MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt**

I have database and has a column "Date_Time" the value of the DateTimePicker is saved to the column Date_Time formatted like this MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt

now i want to get the Time only not the entire value of datetimepicker just the hh:mm tt from the column Date_Time

SORRY FOR MY GRAMMAR

Comment: If you only want to store the time, the database column should be `Time()` otherwise everything will be filling in the date.  `SQl Yog` is not a database, BTW, it is a UI front end for `MySql`

Comment: hahaha Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 2):

How about [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)?

It returns the time that has elapsed since midnight (which is what `h:mm tt` stands for in your code).

```
Dim Time As TimeSpan = DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay 'Would return for example 3:14 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is right.

If you need to get time string, you can use also another way, which includes a formating:

```
Dim myTimeString = DateTimePicker1.value.ToString("hh:mm")
```

You can do that for any part of the DateTime value.

Answer (score 1):

You are heading for a new problem.  If you zero out the Date portion and store the result to a `DateTime` column, you will end up storing something like: `0001-01-01 16:43:12`.  A column defined as `DateTime` will always have a `Date`, as will a `DateTime` variable.

The first problem may be getting `MySQL` to accept a non-Date in a `DateTime` column.  Using a column defined as `DateTime(3)`, mine throws a generic fatal error exception trying to store just a `TimeSpan` to it:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If `MySqlDbType.Time` is used as the type, I get an exception that the time is an invalid value for the column...and it is.

If you manage to store it somehow, the next problem will be when/if you want to put that value back in a `DateTimePicker`: the minimum date you can enter is `1/1/1753` (first full year of the current calendar).  So your `DateTime` var with the `Date` zeroed out wont work.  You'll first have to restore the date portion, but the `Date`, `Year` etc are all readonly.

#### Solution 1

Define the column as `Time(0)` which will store hours, minutes and seconds.  Use the value in the parens to specify fractional seconds, for instance `Time(3)` will also store milliseconds.  When you read the data, store it to a `TimeSpan`.

Then in your UI use a different control, otherwise you have the same problem - adding some Date data to it to make it usable in a `DateTimePicker`

#### Solution 2

Use a `DateTimePicker` and a `DateTime` column, but just ignore the Date portion in your code.  This will allow you to use what is in the Database as is with the control.

You *can* get the time selected with `DateTime.TimeOfDay` but storing and reusing it may be problematic.